# Why is there an error about division by 0?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, error-tracking, field-theory

I'm converting all of my old **Mathematica 7.0** codes to my new **Mathematica 13.2**, and I'm struggling with some issues I didn't encounter with version 7.0.  The following code is giving me a headache, since it worked perfectly with version 7.0 (this is a stripped down version of my full code, which is much more complex).

The following MWE is producing my issue:

```
axe = {0, 1}; (* The magnetic axis *)

coords[s_] = {x[s], z[s]};

r[s_] = Norm[coords[s]];

(* Note:  u is the radius of a spherical hole inside a magnetized sphere *)
dipole[s_, u_] =  Piecewise[{
         {0, (0 <= r[s] < u)}, {1, (r[s] >= u)}
     }] (3 (axe . coords[s]) coords[s]/r[s]^5 - axe/r[s]^3);

(* Note: 0.75 is the magnetic susceptibility of the sphere.  Could be any number *)
Coef1[s_, u_] = Piecewise[{
        {1, (0 <= r[s] < u)},
        {3 (3 - 0.75), (u <= r[s] < 1)},
        {9 (1 - 0.75) + 2 0.75^2 (1 - u^3), (r[s] >= 1)}
    }];

Coef2[s_, u_] = Piecewise[{
        {0, (0 <= r[s] < u)},
        {- 3 0.75 u^3, (u <= r[s] < 1)},
        {0.75 (3 - 0.75) (1 - u^3), (r[s] >= 1)}
    }];

orientation[s_, u_] = Normalize[Coef1[s, u] axe + Coef2[s, u] dipole[s, u]];

nlines = 50;

curves[u_, n_] := curves[u, n] = NDSolve[{
    x'[s] == {1, 0} . orientation[s, u],
    z'[s] == {0, 1} . orientation[s, u],
    x[0] == 0.15 (2 n - 1 - nlines)/2,
    z[0] == -3
    }, {x, z}, {s, 0, 50},
   Method -> BDF, PrecisionGoal -> 6, StoppingTest -> z[s] > 3]

graph[u_, n_] := ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[s], z[s]} /. curves[u, n]], {s, 0, 50}]

Manipulate[Show[Table[graph[u, n], {n, 1, nlines}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    ImageSize -> 600], {{u, 0.5, "Radius"}, 0, 1, 0.01}
    ]
```

The code is numerically solving a differential equation to draw magnetic field lines around and inside a magnetized sphere with a hole inside.  The code works and the output is nice (well at least in my full version), but Mathematica gives me lots of error messages about a **division by 0**.  I'm unable to find what is wrong with the code (which was working without troubles in version 7.0).

So what's wrong in this code?  Where is that division by 0 and how can I fix it?  The only place where I could think of a division by 0 is in the `Normalize` command, for the definition of the function `orientation[s, u]` (the field line orientation should be an unit vector).  But then, the `Piecewise` functions are supposed to prevent any problem here (??).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but can you actually use `NDSolve` here? `x'[s] =={1,0} . orientation[s, u]` has the non-numerical quantity `u` in it and the boundary conditions also depend on the non-numeric quantity `n`. `NDSolve` is only called with one independent variable `s`. Maybe use something like `ParametricNDSolve[{x'[s] == {1, 0} . orientation[s, u], 
   z'[s] == {0, 1} . orientation[s, u], 
   x[0] == 0.15 (2 n - 1 - nlines)/2, z[0] == -3, 
   WhenEvent[z[s] > 3, "StopIntegration"]}, {x, z}, {s, 0, 50}, {u, 
   n}]`?

Comment: @ydd, it doesn't work with this option.  It's actually worst!

Comment: Ah ok. I did get a plot using `ParametricNDSolve` but I have no idea if it's correct. You will probably have to run it on your local device to actually see the plots https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dtrimas/Published/parametric_NDSolve_plot.nb
But it sounds like this is not what you're looking for

Comment: Try `Method -> {BDF, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}`. Getting a real fix might take real work. I happy enough with this (or rather I accept being happy cuz I don't have time for the alternative).

Comment: @MichaelE2, wow!  It works great.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. :) It might be a bug. Like I said, it would take some work to track that down, I suspect. If you have time, consider reporting it to WRI. `NDSolve[]` sets up events to handle `Piecewise[]`. Ideally it improves the solution. Since it's done automatically, I don't think it should result in division by zero. But you could see what WRI says.

Comment: @ydd Option `StoppingTest -> z[s] > 3` in red in v. 13.3 means that this is not an option for `NDSolve`. Therefore option `Method -> {"BDF", "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}` proposed by Michael is some alternative to this in a new version.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, `NDSolve` does work with the non-numeric quantities `u` and `n`? Also the plots I got from `ParametricNDSolve` look similar to the plots generated using `NDSolve` with `Method -> {"BDF", "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}` and removing `StoppingTest -> z[s] > 3` . I am confused why `ParametricNDSolve` is not a good choice here? I am happy to be wrong, I just want to know for closure, and in case I need to do something similar to this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer formed from my comments, which seems to solve the issue:

> Try `Method -> {BDF, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}`. Getting a real fix might take real work. I happy enough with this (or rather I accept being happy cuz I don't have time for the alternative)

> It might be a bug. Like I said, it would take some work to track that down, I suspect. If you have time, consider reporting it to WRI. `NDSolve[]` sets up events to handle `Piecewise[]`. Ideally it improves the solution. Since it's done automatically, I don't think it should result in division by zero. But you could see what WRI says.

If someone wants to take an in-depth look, feel free to build on this and post your own answer.